# Is there a better way to initialize this class? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm passing in a row from a database which is being read in as a tuple. I like the idea of having these attributes readily available for all child classes, but this feels like it could be done without being so many lines. Is there a better method?

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, player_attributes):
        self.player_id = player_attributes[0]
        self.player_first_name = player_attributes[1]
        self.player_last_name = player_attributes[2]
        self.player_date_of_birth = player_attributes[3]
        self.player_city_of_birth = player_attributes[4]
        self.player_state_of_birth = player_attributes[5]
        self.player_height = player_attributes[6]
        self.player_weight = player_attributes[7]
        self.player_age = player_attributes[8]
        self.player_hair_color = player_attributes[9]
        self.player_favorite_food = player_attributes[10]
        self.player_favorite_sport = player_attributes[11]
        ...(20 more attributes)
```

Comment: Have you heard of iterable unpacking?

Comment: *"it could be done without being so many lines"*: well, the names for those properties will have to be typed somewhere... and that is the bulk of your code. Side note: why all these names have to start with `player_` when the class name already gives a hint that these are attributes of a player?

Answer (score 4):

You can use dataclass

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Player:
    player_id: str
    player_first_name: str


player_attributes = ('713', 'Jack')

player: Player = Player(*player_attributes)
print(player)
```

output

```
Player(player_id='713', player_first_name='Jack')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for loop and the `__dict__` attribute maybe.

Use a dictionary instead of a list and this template:

```py
class Test:
     def __init__(self, dictio):
         for k, v in dictio.items():
             self.__dict__[k] = v
```

Comment: `setattr` would be another option to consider.

Comment: *"Use a dictionary instead of a list"* - but..... the input is a tuple from a database...

Answer (score 1):

can you store **player_attributes** like dictionary?if so, you can use such tricky thing:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, d):
        self.__dict__.update(d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A({'k': 123, 'd': 34})
    print(a.k)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `locals()` method to do dynamic assignment.

```
class Player:
  def __init__(self, db_record):
    for i,k in enumerate(('player_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'age')):
        locals()[k] = db_record[i]
    # Clean up local variables
    del db_record
    del i
    del k
    # Assign the local variables to __dict__
    self.__dict__.update(locals())


  def dump(self):
    print(repr(self.__dict__))
```

Comment: Why the use of `locals()`? Why not just `self.__dict__[k] = db_record[i]`? Also why the `del`s? This is Python...

Comment: In the past I have been chewed out by senior developers for adding to `self.__dict__` directly, this was my work around. `locals()` is the local symbol table, it includes the variables `db_record`, `i` and `k` so they must be removed unless we want to keep them as properties of the object.

Comment: This seems very wacky to do a workaround for something you not really going around in the end... You were told not to use `__dict__` but then you use it... So why not make the code more reasonable and just assign to it directly in the loop?

Comment: They originally wanted the constructor to include over 100 manual assignments and wouldn't allow `setattr()` to be used. I was instructed not to directly assign to the `self.__dict__[k]` using a loop as you had suggested and I didn't. Instead I assigned to `locals()` and updated `__dict__` using it. The individual I was dealing with was very pedantic and using `locals()` didn't break their rules possibly because they weren't aware of its existence. I think they prided themselves on the number of lines in the code rather than the maintainability of the code.